# Make Biblatex Output Translator in Bibliograohy

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apacite

I'm quite new Latex so excuse my ignorance. I have translator set in my .bib file however when I use `\printbibliography` no translator is printed. So currently my reference looks like this:

> Surname, A. (2018). Article Title. Journal,10(3),92–101

When it should look like this:

> Surname, A. (2018). Article Title (B. Translator, Trans.). Journal,10(3),92–101

Does the apa style in Biblatex allow for the translator option?

As an aside I found using the `apacite` package would output a translator to the bibliography, however I couldn't find a way to output a full reference (such as what would appear in the bibliography) for my list of figures. I tried using `\caption[{\fullcite]{Figure text}` but I quickly learned `apacite` doesn't have a `\fullcite` equivalent. This prompted my switch to `biblatex` - that and I read the apa style for biblatex is supposed to be the 'correct' way to cite apa in Latex.

Many thanks!

Edit: full example, thanks to samcarter

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\linespread{1.6}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=ynt,language=british]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1: The Problem}
\section{The Reference}
Here is some writing with a citation \parencite[p.6]{reference1}
\printbibliography\newpage
\end{document}
```

**literature.bib**

```
@article{reference1,
    title={The Works of John Smith},
    author={Smith, J.},
    translator={Peter Holmes},
    journal={Science Journal},
    volume={10},
    number={3},
    pages={92-105},
    year={1999},
    language = {german},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks samcarter for the typo corrections! Example added.

Comment: `biblatex-apa` uses translator information for entrytypes `book`, `inbook`, `incollection` and `inproceedings`. But not for other entrytypes, as far as I dug. You have there an `article` entrytype for "The Works of John Smith", are you sure you are using the right entrytype for your actual case?

Comment: Yep, I can confirm it is a journal article which I've had translated.

Comment: If you've had it translated, then aren't you referencing the translation (which is unpublished), rather than the original published article?

Comment: I am yes. However after speaking to university staff they would be happy with the original article being referenced with a translation credit.

Comment: In this particular case where the (I assume unpublished?) translation was especially commissioned for your paper, the `translator` is not really part of the original bibliography data. It might be a good idea to add a `note` explaining that and then it makes sense to mention the translator in that note directly and not in the `translator` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a new macro to output the `translator` for an `article` and then patch the `article` driver to include it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Surname2018,
  author = {Surname, A.},
  date = {2018},
  title = {Article Title},
  translator = {Translator, B.},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume = {10},
  number = {3},
  pages = {92-101}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newbibmacro*{article:trans}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printnames[apanames][-\value{listtotal}]{translator}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
       \printtext{\bibcpstring{translator}}%
       \clearname{translator}}}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{article:trans}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]